# solidity 0.4.25 to 0.5.0

Tags: solidity-0.5.x

when I used 0.4.25, it compiles successfully.

```
function callByFun(address addr)returns (bool){
    bytes4 methodId = bytes4(keccak256("increaseAge(string,uint256)"));
    return addr.call(methodId,"jack", 1);
}
```

Due to some reasons, I have to change to 0.5.0

```
function callByFun(address addr)returns (bool){
    return addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("increaseAge(string,uint256)", "jack", 1));
}
```

and it compiles error

```
browser/ERC865.sol:577:9: TypeError: Different number of arguments in return statement than in returns declaration.
        return addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("increaseAge(string,uint256)", "jack", 1));
        ^---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

How do I revise? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
(bool success,) = addr.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("increaseAge(string,uint256)", "jack", 1));
return success;
```